# Error al instalar Hyper V

Tags: instalacion

Trato de instalar Hyper V, pero me sale error con el codigo 0x80073701
Lo he tradato de solucionar de todas las formas
el procesador si soporta virtualizacion y si la tengo permitida
Alguien lo ha solucionado ?

Comment: Que version de Windows tienes instalada ? Recuerda que en todas las versiones no esta soportado

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Win 10

Comment: Y tu version de Windows 10 es ? Enterprise, Pro o Education

Comment: La falla la da cuando reinicias ?

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Es Win 10 Pro  ..

Comment: @AlejandroMedina no, ni si quiera sale Aplicando Cambios

Comment: Has revisado también que en la BIOS este habilitada para virtualizacion ?

Comment: si tmbn esta activada